# Apache Camel - Stream Closed

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have the following route in Camel:

```
restConfiguration()
            .component("servlet")
            .contextPath(contextPath)
            .host(host)
            .port(port)
            .enableCORS(true);    

rest("/phoneNumbers")
            .put("/{number}")
                .type(PhoneNumber.class)
            .route()
                .streamCaching()
                .from(DIRECT_SETSTATUS_REST)
                .onException(Exception.class).handled(true)
                .to("bean:exceptionProcessor")
                .end()
                .unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, PhoneNumber.class)
                .to("activemq:setStatus?exchangePattern=InOnly");
```

When I send a put request with a valid JSON body, I get the following exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:339) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:152) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.camel.util.IOHelper.copy(IOHelper.java:196) ~[camel-core-2.18.2.jar:2.18.2]
at org.apache.camel.http.common.DefaultHttpBinding.copyStream(DefaultHttpBinding.java:427) ~[camel-http-common-2.18.2.jar:2.18.2]
at org.apache.camel.http.common.DefaultHttpBinding.doWriteDirectResponse(DefaultHttpBinding.java:491) ~[camel-http-common-2.18.2.jar:2.18.2]
at org.apache.camel.http.common.DefaultHttpBinding.doWriteResponse(DefaultHttpBinding.java:390) ~[camel-http-common-2.18.2.jar:2.18.2]
at org.apache.camel.http.common.DefaultHttpBinding.writeResponse(DefaultHttpBinding.java:322) ~[camel-http-common-2.18.2.jar:2.18.2]
at org.apache.camel.http.common.CamelServlet.doService(CamelServlet.java:210) ~[camel-http-common-2.18.2.jar:2.18.2]
at org.apache.camel.http.common.CamelServlet.service(CamelServlet.java:74) ~[camel-http-common-2.18.2.jar:2.18.2]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55) ~[spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:108) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_144]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_144]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_144]
```

But then the message is processed. I can see in the logs that the message went to the queue, and later on it was processed from the queue.

If I remove this line:

```
.unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, PhoneNumber.class)
```

Then I don't get the exception, but I would like to keep it to parse into POJO.  Any idea of what's causing the exception?

Comment: I'm confused about your `from(direct....)` definition inside the route. You get your payload from an HTTP endpoint invocation not from a direct endpoint, so what is the use of it in the route? I'm also not sure if this does work in general, but haven't tried that yet, tbh. Next, do you really need the stream data once you converted it to a PhoneNumber object?

Comment: I addition to that, you already defined that the payload should be mapped to a `PhoneNumber` instance via `.type(PhoneNumber)` why do you need to convert it later on on using `.unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, PhoneNumber.class)`? Use either one or the other

Answer (score 1):

If you get rid of `.unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, PhoneNumber.class)` & `.streamcaching()`

and use

```
.put("/{number}")
  .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json)
  .type(PhoneNumber.class)
  .consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)`
```

it should work properly

Answer (score 0):

To be able to read stream more than once you can use "stream caching". Details: http://camel.apache.org/stream-caching.html

Comment: Hi, I'm already using streamcaching() but still having the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, add

```
.setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
```

at the end of the route.